# JavaScript prevent changing exported object

Tags: javascript, export, global-variables

Is there any way to prevent exported object to be changed later when it's imported ? 
I have my config.js helper that manages my config, and I want to export config but I want to only allow changes inside that config.js

```js
let config = null

const refreshConfig = async () => {
  config = {something: "newvalue"}
}

export {config, refreshConfig}
```

but this way, I am allowed to change it somewhere else like:

```js
import {config} from 'config.js'

config.something = "changing it now"
```

how to prevent that scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. If you don't need to change the config object's property values within the module, [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it when loading it:

   ```
   config = Object.freeze({something: "new value"});
   ```

   You can still *replace* it (inside the module), you just can't change property values on it.
2. Export a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that only allows allows retrieving information, not updating it.

   ```
   let realConfig = null;

   const config = new Proxy({}, {
       get(target, propName) {
           return realConfig && realConfig[propName];
       }
   });
   ```

   *(You might choose to implement more proxy traps than just `get`.)*
3. Export a function that allows the caller to receive a defensive copy of the config, not the actual config.

#1 seems most applicable to the code in the question.

Comment: ah brilliant, completely forgot about Object.freeze. That's what I needed. thank you. And thank you for other answer that will be handy in the future